# Trying to find distinct positive integers from 1 to n such that they add up to s, random number pops up in a for loop

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to make a C++ program to find numbers from `1 to n` (and their count) such that they add up to `s`, I've hit time limits so I was trying to optimise it by calculating sum only once and then mutating it. In the `for` loop in the `removeStuff` function, `i` becomes a random number even though `length` isn't.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long

//ll sumArray(ll arr[], ll length) {
//    ll sum = 0;
//    for (ll i = 0; i < length; i++) {
//        sum += arr[i];
//    }
//    return sum;
//}

void printArray(ll arr[], ll length) {
    string w;
    ll count = 0;
    for (ll i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != 0) {
            count += 1;
            w += to_string(arr[i]) + " ";
        }
    }
    cout <<count<<" " << w<< endl;
}

void removeStuff(long long arr[], long long length, long long target, ll sum) {
    if (sum == target) {
        printArray(arr, length);
        return;
    }

    for (long long i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (sum - arr[i] > target && arr[i] != 0) {
            sum = sum - arr[i];
            arr[i] = 0;
            if (sum == target) {
                printArray(arr, length);
                return;
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
}


ll sum(ll n) {
    return (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
}

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int testCases;
    cin >> testCases;

    while (testCases--) {
        ll n, s;
        cin >> n >> s;
        if (sum(n) < s) {
            cout << -1 << endl;
            continue;
        } else if (sum(n) == s) {
            string w;
            for (ll i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                w += " " + to_string(i);
            }
            cout << n << " " << w << endl;
            continue;
        } else {
            if (n >= s) {
                cout << "1 " << s << endl;
                continue;
            } else if (s % n < n && n+n > s) {
                cout << "2 " << n << " " << s - n << endl;
                continue;
            } else {
                 ll arr[n];
                 ll sum = 0;
                 for (ll i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                     arr[i] = i + 1;
                     sum = sum + i + 1;
                 }

                removeStuff(arr, n, s, sum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I use the input `1 4 9`.

For reference, here is a screenshot of [my debugger results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXR9D.png)

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this bug with your specified input. I tried to reproduce it with the compilers gcc and clang. Which compiler and operating system are you using? Is your debugger screenshot from the first iteration of the loop or from a later iteration?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that this error occurs using the input you specified? Since you do not perform any input validation, providing incorrect input will probably cause your program to invoke undefined behavior. As far as I can tell, this does not occur with the input you provided, but it may occur if the input is slightly different.

Comment: Yes, I'm using clang on macOS, using CLion, if that matters, it uses the one in the `Xcode-beta` version of Xcode, not the stable one, but I highly doubt that matters